# Where do Android apps save their working state?

Tags: applications, root-access, backup, internal-storage

Where do apps store their working state?

Occasionally an app will crash, or I'll get the Android message that X app has stopped responding ("Do you wish to close?"). In either of those cases, after the app has crashed/closed, if I then switch back to the app via the switcher, the app's state is restored right in the middle of where it was previously, as if it had never closed.

However, if I were to close the app myself, such as closing it from the app-switcher view, or the phone rebooted, the app will start fresh, with no state saved/restored whatsoever.

I'm wondering if there's a way to manually save an app's working state, so you could restore the state manually within the app when you want, without the assistance of the "App isn't responding, do you want to close?"